# How to solve wrong HEIGHT of IMAGEVIEW in percentage in Android

Tags: android, imageview, height, android-linearlayout, percentage

I´ve tried a few thinks to achive the following thing:

For the discription: I want to have a header with a textview which wraps over the howl page and below this header I want to display three images beside each other. It should be like a image gallery. This layout i want to duplicate.

But my problem is, that I the height of the ImageView is to high and that there is a distance between the sized image and the title. See figure.

[image: What I want and What I got]

On the Left is what I want and on the right is what I got...

Here is my layout code:

```js
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="titel"
            android:id="@+id/titel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titel">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.208"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:src="@drawable/1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.389"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:src="@drawable/2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.403"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:src="@drawable/3"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my best guess is because your `ImageView` scales your image in a way that it fits into the center of the view and leaves empty space around the top and bottom of the view. try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView` in the xml.

on a side note, when debugging view hierarchy, it's almost always gonna be helpful to go to `Android Device Monitor`, select your devices to the right, and click `Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator`. You can easily find out which view is taking the extra space by hovering your mouse over different view elements.